# How to align labels properly in a stack panel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend, stackpanel

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

As you can see there is a title "This is what I want" that is aligned with 
another label

**Code that I wrote:**

```
      <Grid Width="345" Height="445" Background="White">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                <Label Content="How to align this to the left:" />
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#D9D9D9">
                    <Label Content="€" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Label Content="256,00" FontSize="38" FontWeight="Bold" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And results of my code looks like this:
[image]

As it is possible to notice, label is not aligned to the left, looks like there is some padding or something...

And also € sign is not on a right place, I tried to achieve this like it's on first image, but everything I tried with different types of aligns (horizontal, centered) did not work..

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: Firstly, remove `Margin` from `StackPanel` element. If you want to move euro sign to right, set `Margin` to second `StackPanel`. And your grid hasn't `Row` 1.

Comment: Set the Padding of the Label to 0.

Comment: @mm8 that's what I figured out for title above number, but how to align € sign properly? to be in a same line as a number  in another label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Padding` of the `Label` to `0` or use a `TextBlock`. A TextBlock is more light-weight than a `Label` and it has no default `Padding`.

And you can use the `Margin` property to move the €-sign up a bit:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
    <TextBlock Text="How to align this to the left:" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#D9D9D9">
        <TextBlock Text="€" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Margin="0 0 3 5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="256,00" FontSize="38" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```